# Satis circular dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist, satis

I have a project with multiple packages
Each package is in a private git repository.

Some of the packages have dependencies of each other.

You can check here how my satis http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBOEQW page looks like.

Now if I clone the project-xpto/core, and run a composer update i get this:

> ➜  php-core git:(master) composer update
>       Loading composer repositories with package information
>       Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>       Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> ```
>   Problem 1
>     - Installation request for project-xpto/event dev-master -> satisfiable by project-xpto/event[dev-master].
>     - project-xpto/event dev-master requires project-xpto/activity-streams dev-master -> no matching package found.
>   Problem 2
>     - Installation request for project-xpto/tool dev-master -> satisfiable by project-xpto/tool[dev-master].
>     - project-xpto/tool dev-master requires project-xpto/activity-streams dev-master -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>  - A typo in the package name
>  - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>    see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion>
> ```
>
> for more details.
>
> ```
> Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
> ```

- satis.json => http://pastie.org/private/s0e2rxtnvpv9g7rpp415a
- composer.json xpto-core => http://pastie.org/10062586
- composer.json xpto-event => http://pastie.org/private/stxe2sbwpja8088knrldq
- composer.json xpto-tool =>
  http://pastie.org/private/11o9wv94kvfprl5wjfibrq
- composer.json
  xpto-activity-streams =>
  http://pastie.org/private/plieipe2gco1yt4gs0jxg

Isn't suppose to satis resolve all dependencies and all work fine?

What i'm doing wrong?

If you need anything else, just ask i will update here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please give this a try:

add `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to the `composer.json` of `project-xpto/core`.

You require a lot of `dev-master` stability packages, but the default minimum-stability is `stable`. So they are not resolved to a stable set. You need to lower stability for all packages to `dev` by setting the above directive in your main projects composer.json.

Alternatively you could use `dev-master@dev` to lower stability on a specific package. But here it's quite a number of packages, so i would suggest to set minimum-stability dev for the whole project.

---

You can combine "minimum-stability dev" with "prefer-stable true".
This tells Composer to resolve to stable versions AND ONLY if stable could not be resolved, use a dev dependency. This setting is a good way in the starting phase of a private project, where packages start to grow out of "dev-master" and into "stable versions".

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true
```

Comment: you sir, save me from some hard hours! But just to confirm, this is a kind of migration from svn to git/satis, and for now they are just blank skeletons with no code, i should create new branches on git repos named as 'dev'/'stable'? for now i just got 'master', and created some tags.. What is the best practise?

Comment: I append my answer with a short notice about "prefer-stable" in combination with "minimum-stability".

Comment: Glad i could help :) "Best practice" - hmm, i think, when it's a fresh project or a migration it's okay to work with stability dev on the whole project. But the goal "should be" to get each package into a stable version, even if that is just a tiny v0.1. Start version tagging early in packages. Then you can remove minimum-stability dev from the main project and start using version constraints fetching stable versions, like "1.0.0" to get the latest stable version or "~1.0". In other words: goal is to have a main project composed out of stable packages.

Comment: I cannot stress enough that using tagged version requirements is the only way to use Composer without getting insane. Using branches however will always lead to misery and pain - that's my experience from reading and answering hundreds of Composer related questions.